# How to replace backslash followed by 't' or any other alphabet or character in escape chacter in file path to forward slash in java?

Tags: java, string, filepath, backslash

I'm importing a CSV file to MySQL database. This can be done using java.mysql support for forward slash in file path. If user gives the path

```
String filepath=" c:\upload\date\csv\sample.csv";
```

we can do it by replacing `'\'` with `'/'` using following line of code.

```
String filepath2=filepath.replace("\\","/");
```

but when user enters path as follows

```
String filepath=" c:\test.csv";
```

the replace function unable to replace `"\\"` with `"/"`

as `'\'` in the filepath does not remain `'\'` as `'\'` is followed by 't' and it becomes as `'\t'` escape character.
this type of problem will come with each and every escape sequence.

I want to search for backslashes in the path and replace them with a forward slash, to give this:

```
c:/test.csv
```

How is that done?
How to solve this problem?

Comment: What you describe won't help, because the the replacement from e.g. `\t` to TAB happens so early that it even won't appear in the string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape the backslashes and the automatically generated escape character in file path in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553634/how-to-escape-the-backslashes-and-the-automatically-generated-escape-character-in)

Comment: You need to distinguish between the *user* entering a path, and a path appearing in Java source code. I doubt that the user is writing source code...

Comment: Like @JonSkeet is saying, you will not have this problem when you get the string `filepath` from user input. It is the Java compiler that translates `\t` into tab characters, so it will obviously happen only in your actual source code.

Comment: @Jon Skeet @ Daniel Brockman I am getting the file path using JFileChooser. Daniel Brockman sir please tell me how to avoid the conversion to '\t'?

Comment: You don't need to do this. You have misunderstood your problem completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're getting the value via JFileChooser, then it will be more like this:

```
String value = "c:\\test.csv"; // This really only has a single backslash
```

But you shouldn't need to replace the backslashes with forward slashes. My *guess* is that you're including the value directly in the SQL you're generating: *don't do that*. Use a prepared statement with parameters instead, and you may well find the problem just goes away... and suddenly you won't be as vulnerable to SQL injection attacks either...

If you *really, really* need to convert backslashes to forward slashes, you can use:

```
String newValue = oldValue.replace("\\", "/");
```

... but you *shouldn't* have to do this.

Comment: Hello Sir! Actually the path getting from JFileChooser is shown in JtextField then its stored in a String object and I am using that String object directly in my Load data in localfile query. so it gives problem there for the path that you mention because it has only one backward slash before 't'. And the path in the string object has only single backslash. So I tried to replace with two backslashes wiht replace function but it fails.

Comment: @Param-Ganak: *Why* would you try to replace one backslash with two? It should be fine as it is. It sounds like the problem is in the code you're *using* the string with, but you haven't shown us what that code is *or* told us what problem it causes.