# How to make the JFileChooser to return the file or directory path containing the forward slash in stead of backward slash in java?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have implemented JFileChooser of Java swing successfully. As the implemented JFileChooser gives file or directory path with backward slash as a file separator on windows os. 
My question is how to make this JFileChooser to return the file or directory path containing the forward slash in stead of backward slash as path separator in java independent of windows os or any other os?

Please guide me Friends!

Thank You!

Comment: Why not replace the backward slash in the returned file paht?

Comment: @Gandalf Please check my question on Stackoverflow : How to replace backward slash followed by 't' or any other alphabet or character in escape chacter in file path to forward slash in java? You will get the exact problem. Thank You

Comment: No I don't think so! The path in this other question was entered as String literal in source code. JFileChooser will not include escape sequences in its output.

Comment: DYM http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554361/how-to-replace-backward-slash-followed-by-t-or-any-other-alphabet-or-character

Comment: @Param - you seem to be a bit confused - you confuse string literals and strings as is evidenced by your other question.

Comment: @Param-Ganak: It's the third question you ask for the same problem. The answer has been given multiple times already. You only have to escape backslashes in String literals. Not in strings entered by the user in a GUI. Do you actually read the answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you don't have to care about forward/backward slashes. The JFileChooser will return the path so that it is suitable for the machine it is running on.

Comment: Please check my question on Stackoverflow : How to replace backward slash followed by 't' or any other alphabet or character in escape chacter in file path to forward slash in java? You will get the exact problem. Thank You

Comment: You don't have to care about that, either. A \t in a String (on the console) is not a TAB character (which is \t in a String *literal*)

Answer (score 1):

The `File` class actually abstracts you of this task. The JFileChooser return a File object, then you can call its `getCanonicalPath` method (for instance) which has a different format depending on the OS.