# Prevent a LinkButton inside ItemTemplate from postback and execute a javascript function using Evaluated val as parameter

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I dont know why this is giving me such a hard time, may be coding all day long has finally made my head smoke. I am trying to call a js function on client click of a link button inside an item template. I am using the Eval method to pass one of the parameters to my js function and prevent postback. However, it postbacks and never calls my function. If i take the evaluated parameter it works.

```
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="media_id" Visible="false" HeaderText="" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="dir_path" Visible="false" HeaderText="" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Taken">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="dateLinkCsBtn" OnClientClick='<%#Eval("dir_path","javascript:return test({0},event);")%>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("dir_path") %>'
                        runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("date") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="description" Visible="true" HeaderText="Media Type" />
        </Columns>
```

and this is the js function:

```
<script>
    function test(dir_path,event) {
        alert(dir_path);
        event.preventDefault();

    };        
</script>
```

UPDATE : Replacing OnClientClick from

```
OnClientClick='<%#Eval("dir_path","javascript:return test({0},event);")%>'
```

to :

```
OnClientClick='<%#Eval("dir_path","Javascript:return test(\"{0}\",event);")%>'
```

Works but the output produced ignores all '\' and returns :
     `C:KBlog_MediaColorSnapshota4dde1-76fc-4e2e-9100-f12f48427e24.png`  instead of

```
C:\KBlog_Media\1\ColorSnapshot\00a4dde1-76fc-4e2e-9100-f12f48427e24.png
```

SOLUTION: Update the datasource datatable of the gridview to display double backslash for dir_path "\" instead of single backslash. It worked like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the function test should return false if you don't want an postback. The CommandArgument attribute is used only if you use the OnCommand event;

Comment: i tried that and it still post backs, if i take the evaluated parameter out it works as it should without postback.

Comment: Could you call directly the test function without the eval only for test, so OnClientClick="javascript:return test('value');"

Comment: Could you see the html generated for that linkbutton, and check if the  javascript call to the test function don't have syntax errors.

Comment: I think you should call the function in this way OnClientClick='<%#Eval("dir_path","javascript:return test(**'{0}'**);")%>'

Comment: it works like this OnClientClick='<%#Eval("dir_path","Javascript:return test(\"{0}\",event);")%>' . However this escapes '\' and prints C:KBlog_MediaColorSnapshota4dde1-76fc-4e2e-9100-f12f48427e24.png  instead of C:\KBlog_Media\1\ColorSnapshot\00a4dde1-76fc-4e2e-9100-f12f48427e24.png which i need for string manipulation

Comment: Yeah I just was going to suggest that, You are rigth, but if you see the generated code it have the correct string, I think in javascript you have this problem is because it treat the (backslash + character) \character as a escape sentence, you must escape the \ with \\ so C:\\KBlog_Media\\1\\ColorSnapshot\\00a4dde1-76fc-4e2e-9100-f12f48427e24.png, I thik with this we correct your problem

Comment: anyway to prevent that ?

Comment: To prevent to escape the '\' backslash character in the javascript.

Comment: how do i do this? i am new to the world of javascript

Comment: The concept is the same as the C# or Java language for example if you want a new line you scape the string with the \n or a tab with \t, it basically is the same for javascript, so when you pass the string C:\KBlog_Media\1\C as parameter of function javascript tries to escape the \ character. So to avoid this behavior we need to escape the backslash with \\ the javascript will not try to escape character.

Comment: so how do i prevent it from doing this when the parameter is being passed in OnClientClick='<%#Eval("dir_path","Javascript:return test(\"{0}\",event);")%>'

Comment: Ok, As you are getting the data from database you could use the RowDataBound event to modify the value of the dir_path you use the replace function dir_path.replace("\", "\\"). The other option is to change the value in the database but I don't recommend you to do it.

Comment: where does this escape backslash ?

Comment: The string C:\KBlog_Media\1\ColorSnapshot\00a4dde1-76fc-4e2e-9100-f12f48427e24.png must be C:\\KBlog_Media\\1\\ColorSnapshot\\00a4dde1-76fc-4e2e-9100-f12f48427e24.png with double \\. You can change it in the database or in the RowDataBound event.

Comment: Here it is another post with the problem that I mention: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553634/how-to-escape-the-backslashes-and-the-automatically-generated-escape-character-i

Comment: i got the output for dir_path to look like this C:\\KBlog_Media\\1\\ColorSnapshot\\00a4dde1-76fc-4e2e-9100-f12f48427e24.png but it still escapes it. No matter how many backslashes i replace it with (tried 2, 3 , and 4 backslashes)

Comment: RowDataBound event occurs too late i guess, the eval function happens before it

Comment: That is weird, I made a test in my web site and it correct the problem could you see the generated code and post how it call the javascript function.

Comment: solved it by manipulating the data in the datatable that serves as a datasource for the gridview

Comment: what i had for rowdatabound was this         protected void searchGV_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                string val= e.Row.Cells[1].Text.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
                e.Row.Cells[1].Text = val;

            }
        }

Comment: That is great yes that was the suggestion that I made could you vote for my answer, thanks

Comment: thank you for the help. I dont know why rowDataBound did not solve it for me =\