# Escape \n in pathname to use os python module

Tags: python-2.7, operating-system

I have a path of the form 
    `input_path=C:\Users\ngv\workspace\filename1.`

I am using 
    `dir,file = os.path.split(input_path).`

This prints:
`dir= C:\Users

gv\workspace` by treating \n of \ngv as newline

and `file = filename1`.
How do I fix this? I cannot seem to find any way to escape \n.
I tried `input_path=input_path.replace('\n','\\n')` and `input_path.replace('\\n','\\\n')` with failed results.

Please note that I am using exec() in python. And it is during this exec() invoke that the file path name changes.

Comment: Where does `input_path=C:\Users\ngv\workspace\filename1` come from ? Have you written that directly in your source code ? In which case you should write `input_path='C:\\Users\\ngv\\workspace\\filename1'` or `input_path=r'C:\Users\ngv\workspace\filename1'`

Comment: Its coming from a different function as an argument here. When I print it here it already prints with \n treated as new line.

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553634/how-to-escape-the-backslashes-and-the-automatically-generated-escape-character-i worked for me.