# java.io.FileNotFoundException though file is present

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have written below a basic code regarding reading the excel data from eclispse. I have saved the program as `UFT-8`.

The program ended with `java.io.FileNotFoundException` which states that no file exists. But I have saved the file in this location `E:\\New.xlsx`.

I am using windows 10 and eclipse version is LUNA.The program is below:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
public class ExcelRead {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException   {   
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("‪‪E:\\New.xlsx");
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
        String s = wb.getSheet("Sheet1").getRow(0).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: What has this question to do with Selenium Webdriver? This is a pure Java question....

Comment: Your question is very difficult to read. You should format it using the tools provided to make it more readable.

Comment: I want to read data from excel. I have written this code in eclipse. While reading data from excel it is throwing error as "java.io.FileNotFoundException" . But the excel file is there. Also, have you faced this kind of issue. If yes kindly share it.

Comment: I know it's bit old now, but did u find the solution? if so could u plz share it

Answer (score 0):

Try using "E:\\New.xlsx" instead. That question is something you may need: [How to escape the backslashes and the automatically generated escape character in file path in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553634/how-to-escape-the-backslashes-and-the-automatically-generated-escape-character-i).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes in code I have written the same thing "E:\\New.xlsx". But still error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try forward slash in selenium WebDriver 
eg: C:/Users/Folder/git/MyLocalRepository/LifeStyle/Excel_Library/Excel.xlsx

It will work.